# scrcpy access problem with Linux

Tags: linux, usb-debugging, developer-options, scrcpy

I have 2 Android devices: a tablet from Denver and a cell phone from Xiaomi (Redmi 9C), I installed scrcpy on my MX Linux pc, I have no problem to access tablet through `scrcpy`, but when I tried with Redmi 9C, I can only see it, the mouse does not work, did I miss some settings? The developer option is enabled (is there any other options inside developer options that I need to change/enable? I only enabled developer options).
note:

1. I've tried enable file transfer when plugin the USB cable, seems to make no difference and `adb device` command can see this device.
2. adb version 1.0.41

Comment: Looking at the [issues page of scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues) it seems that there are quite a few devices which have problems with scrcpy.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution given by alecxs.

Add Mi account and enable USB debugging (Security settings) option under Developer options.

[image]